# Error in creating instance of a class viewModel

Tags: android, android-room, android-viewmodel

I am just trying to learn Room. So I created a sample application using the guidelines provided by Google in [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-room-with-a-view/#0). I am getting a following error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.brahma/com.brahma.ui.SignUpActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.brahma.viewModel.UserViewModel
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot create an instance of class com.brahma.viewModel.UserViewModel
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:207)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102)
        at com.brahma.ui.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:72)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199)
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
        at com.brahma.ui.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:72) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807) 
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.assertNotMainThread(RoomDatabase.java:164)
        at android.arch.persistence.room.RoomDatabase.query(RoomDatabase.java:192)
        at com.brahma.Room.UserDao_Impl.getUser(UserDao_Impl.java:56)
        at com.brahma.repository.UserRepository.<init>(UserRepository.java:18)
        at com.brahma.viewModel.UserViewModel.<init>(UserViewModel.java:17)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider$AndroidViewModelFactory.create(ViewModelProvider.java:199) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:134) 
        at android.arch.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider.get(ViewModelProvider.java:102) 
        at com.brahma.ui.SignUpActivity.onCreate(SignUpActivity.java:72) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7036) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7027) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1215) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2731) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2856) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6501) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

I tried to look for the solution on internet but didn't get the success. The  solutions available on stackOverflow ask to make the constructor public of viewModel, which my costructor already is.

Here is my viewModel:

```
public class UserViewModel extends AndroidViewModel{

    private UserRepository mUserRepository;
    private User mUserInfo;

    public UserViewModel( Application application) {
        super(application);
        mUserRepository = new UserRepository(application);
        mUserInfo = mUserRepository.getmUserInfo();
    }


    public User getUserInfo(){
        return mUserInfo;
    }
    public void insert(User user){
        mUserRepository.insert(user);
    }
}
```

Below is my activity where I am instantiating the viewModel:

```
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this, getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
        initViews();

        mUserViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(UserViewModel.class);

        callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
        mGoogleSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        mFacebookSignUp.setOnClickListener(this);
        initGoogleApiClient();
    }
```

I have no idea what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

As it says within your callstack near the bottom, you're calling a database query on the main thread.

```
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.
```

With Room, you cannot make requests on the UI thread and I believe it's because of this line.

```
mUserInfo = mUserRepository.getmUserInfo();
```

If you're using Room and ViewModels, simply use `LiveData`. The end product will also be a lot easier to work with.

Comment: I think its not because of that I just tried to extend viewModel instead of AndroidViewModel and the error related to database disappear. But the main issue creating a viewModel instance is still there

Comment: Have you tried removing the database logic from the ViewModel and running it?

Answer (score 0):

I just found the solution to my problem.

ViewModelProvider which is use to create a new instance of viewModel class always calls the default constructor. Since in my application I haven't declared the default constructor that's why it was throwing me the error "**Can not create instance of a class ViewModel**". So you have to create a default constructor in your ViewModel class.

In case if you don't want to create a default constructor or want to create a different constructor as in my case, you have to create a view model provider factory.

[Here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-architecture-components/blob/master/BasicRxJavaSample/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/observability/ui/UserActivity.java) you can provide an example how to create a factory class for your viewModel.

Hope this solution help you in understanding the ViewModel much better.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are trying to run query on main thread.
You can solve this problem in 2 ways :

1.In your repository class use Asynctask inside `mUserRepository.getmUserInfo()` while getting Data  of Type List or Type of User in Your case. will solve your issue.

2.Calling `allowMainThreadQueries()` will solve this issues.
You need to call `allowMainThreadQueries()` in RoomDatabase instance like this :

```
//where INSTANCE is of type Database
    public static Database getDatabase(final Context context) {
        if (INSTANCE == null) {
            synchronized (Database.class) {
                if (INSTANCE == null) {
                    INSTANCE = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                            Database.class, DATABASE_NAME)
                            // Wipes and rebuilds instead of migrating if no Migration object.
                            // Migration is not part of this codelab.
                            .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                            //allows queries to execute on main thread
                            .allowMainThreadQueries()
                            //.addCallback(sRoomDatabaseCallback)
                            .build();

                }
            }
        }
        return INSTANCE;
    }
```